# Size_hint and pos_hint of kivy not working when adding buttons programmatically in python

Tags: python, kivy

I am querying Mongolab for the number of documents in a collection, then I want to add one button per document found. I put this code in the on_enter function of a screen:

```
def on_enter(self):
    topicconcepts = db.topicconcepts
    topics = topicconcepts.distinct("topic")

    for idx, topic in enumerate(topics):
        button = Button(text=topic, id=str(idx), buttonPos = idx, size=(self.width,20), pos_hint = {'top': 1}, color= (1,1,1,1), halign='center', seq = 'pre')
        # topicBox points to a BoxLayout
        self.topicBox.add_widget(button)
```

However, the layout turns out to be this:

[image]

Basically I want the buttons to be more like this:
[image]

Any suggestions will be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have fixed size buttons in a GridLayout (or a BoxLayout), you have to unset their size_hints. For example, for fixed height of 50dp, without changing width, it would be:

```
Button:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: '50dp'
```

on in py:

```
from kivy.metrics import dp
Button(size_hint_y=None, height=dp(50))
```

PS: remember, the buttons might overflow the screen, if too many topics are given. To correct this, use [ScrollView](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html) widget to scroll them up and down.